# What is libapt-inst1.7 and where do i download it?

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install Synaptic, but the software center is giving me the following error:
Dependency is not satisfiable: libapt-inst1.7 (>=0.8.16~exp12).
The same happened before with various other programs, so im guessing this is a driver of some sort?

Comment: Are you really using Ubuntu 14.04 as the tag suggests? Because  only in Ubuntu 15.10 `synaptic` depends on `libapt-inst1.7`.

Comment: Yes, I am using 14.04.

Comment: @BerryM. in that case you should focus on *why* your system apparently wants a non-standard version of the package. Have you added any PPAs or modified your sources.list file?

Comment: @BerryM: What's the output of `apt-cache policy synaptic` on the command line?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch 
installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.81.1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.81.1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     0.81.1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: @steeldriver No, I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Package `libapt-inst1.7` is a deb package format runtime library.

You can download it at:

[64 bits](http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-inst1.7_1.0.10.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

[32 bits](http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-inst1.7_1.0.10.2ubuntu1_i386.deb)

Comment: Thank you. I'm missing another dependency though, so could you show me where to find those?

Comment: Yes, at: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @BerryM. you shouldn't really be needing to download and install individual `.deb` files manually: that's a quick way to get your package management system tied in knots (the equivalent of Windows "dll hell")

Comment: @steeldriver how would you suggest I install them then? Did I do something wrong when installing ubuntu?